# RuntimeError with LightningModule: Parameters that were not used in producing the loss returned by training_step

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I've got an issue when moving from single-GPU training to multi-GPU training with PytorchLightning (version 2.1.0) using DPP as a training strategy. This is the error I get:

```
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0,1]
LOCAL_RANK: 1 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0,1]

  | Name          | Type             | Params
---------------------------------------------------
0 | model         | Unet             | 10.0 M
1 | _loss         | CrossEntropyLoss | 0     
2 | train_metrics | MetricCollection | 0     
3 | val_metrics   | MetricCollection | 0     
4 | test_metrics  | MetricCollection | 0     
---------------------------------------------------
10.0 M    Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
10.0 M    Total params
40.186    Total estimated model params size (MB)
Epoch 0:   1%|▏                     | 1/167 [00:01<03:58,  0.70it/s, v_num=hyxf]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/pathology/users/linda/pytorch-segmentation-models/source/run_segmentation_module.py", line 110, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/data/pathology/users/linda/pytorch-segmentation-models/source/run_segmentation_module.py", line 93, in main
    trainer.fit(segmentation_module, datawrapper.training_generator, datawrapper.validation_generator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 545, in fit
    call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 43, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=trainer, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/launchers/subprocess_script.py", line 102, in launch
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 581, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 990, in _run
    results = self._run_stage()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1036, in _run_stage
    self.fit_loop.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py", line 202, in run
    self.advance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py", line 359, in advance
    self.epoch_loop.run(self._data_fetcher)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/training_epoch_loop.py", line 136, in run
    self.advance(data_fetcher)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/training_epoch_loop.py", line 240, in advance
    batch_output = self.automatic_optimization.run(trainer.optimizers[0], batch_idx, kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 187, in run
    self._optimizer_step(batch_idx, closure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 265, in _optimizer_step
    call._call_lightning_module_hook(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 157, in _call_lightning_module_hook
    output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 1282, in optimizer_step
    optimizer.step(closure=optimizer_closure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/optimizer.py", line 151, in step
    step_output = self._strategy.optimizer_step(self._optimizer, closure, **kwargs)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/ddp.py", line 263, in optimizer_step
    optimizer_output = super().optimizer_step(optimizer, closure, model, **kwargs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 230, in optimizer_step
    return self.precision_plugin.optimizer_step(optimizer, model=model, closure=closure, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py", line 117, in optimizer_step
    return optimizer.step(closure=closure, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 280, in wrapper
    out = func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 33, in _use_grad
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/optim/adamw.py", line 148, in step
    loss = closure()
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py", line 104, in _wrap_closure
    closure_result = closure()
                     ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 140, in __call__
    self._result = self.closure(*args, **kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 126, in closure
    step_output = self._step_fn()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 315, in _training_step
    training_step_output = call._call_strategy_hook(trainer, "training_step", *kwargs.values())
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 309, in _call_strategy_hook
    output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 381, in training_step
    return self._forward_redirection(self.model, self.lightning_module, "training_step", *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 628, in __call__
    wrapper_output = wrapper_module(*args, **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1139, in forward
    if torch.is_grad_enabled() and self.reducer._rebuild_buckets():
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: It looks like your LightningModule has parameters that were not used in producing the loss returned by training_step. If this is intentional, you must enable the detection of unused parameters in DDP, either by setting the string value `strategy='ddp_find_unused_parameters_true'` or by setting the flag in the strategy with `strategy=DDPStrategy(find_unused_parameters=True)`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/pathology/users/linda/pytorch-segmentation-models/source/run_segmentation_module.py", line 110, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/data/pathology/users/linda/pytorch-segmentation-models/source/run_segmentation_module.py", line 93, in main
    trainer.fit(segmentation_module, datawrapper.training_generator, datawrapper.validation_generator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 545, in fit
    call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 43, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=trainer, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/launchers/subprocess_script.py", line 102, in launch
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 581, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 990, in _run
    results = self._run_stage()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1036, in _run_stage
    self.fit_loop.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py", line 202, in run
    self.advance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py", line 359, in advance
    self.epoch_loop.run(self._data_fetcher)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/training_epoch_loop.py", line 136, in run
    self.advance(data_fetcher)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/training_epoch_loop.py", line 240, in advance
    batch_output = self.automatic_optimization.run(trainer.optimizers[0], batch_idx, kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 187, in run
    self._optimizer_step(batch_idx, closure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 265, in _optimizer_step
    call._call_lightning_module_hook(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 157, in _call_lightning_module_hook
    output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 1282, in optimizer_step
    optimizer.step(closure=optimizer_closure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/optimizer.py", line 151, in step
    step_output = self._strategy.optimizer_step(self._optimizer, closure, **kwargs)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/ddp.py", line 263, in optimizer_step
    optimizer_output = super().optimizer_step(optimizer, closure, model, **kwargs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 230, in optimizer_step
    return self.precision_plugin.optimizer_step(optimizer, model=model, closure=closure, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py", line 117, in optimizer_step
    return optimizer.step(closure=closure, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 280, in wrapper
    out = func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 33, in _use_grad
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/optim/adamw.py", line 148, in step
    loss = closure()
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py", line 104, in _wrap_closure
    closure_result = closure()
                     ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 140, in __call__
    self._result = self.closure(*args, **kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 126, in closure
    step_output = self._step_fn()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 315, in _training_step
    training_step_output = call._call_strategy_hook(trainer, "training_step", *kwargs.values())
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 309, in _call_strategy_hook
    output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 381, in training_step
    return self._forward_redirection(self.model, self.lightning_module, "training_step", *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 628, in __call__
    wrapper_output = wrapper_module(*args, **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1139, in forward
    if torch.is_grad_enabled() and self.reducer._rebuild_buckets():
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: It looks like your LightningModule has parameters that were not used in producing the loss returned by training_step. If this is intentional, you must enable the detection of unused parameters in DDP, either by setting the string value `strategy='ddp_find_unused_parameters_true'` or by setting the flag in the strategy with `strategy=DDPStrategy(find_unused_parameters=True)`.
```

The code for `training_step` looks like this:

```
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        preds = self.forward(x)
        # loss
        loss = self.compute_loss(preds, y)
        self.log(f'train/loss', loss, on_epoch=True, on_step=False, sync_dist=True)
        # metrics
        performance = self.train_metrics(preds, y.squeeze(dim=1))
        performance = pretty_print_performance(performance)
        for metric, val in performance.items():
            self.log(f'train/{metric}', val, on_epoch=True, on_step=False, sync_dist=True)
        return loss

    def compute_loss(self, preds, y):
        if self.loss in ['DiceLoss', 'LovaszLoss']:
            loss = self.loss(preds, y)
        else:
            loss = self.loss(preds, y.squeeze(dim=1))
        return loss
```

The function is not returning anything besides the loss, so I am confused as to what this error message means and how to fix it.

I'm using the torch CrossEntropyLoss and AdamW optimizer without a scheduler.

Additional version info: Python 3.11.3, torch 2.0.1+cu118